# What are the disadvantages of the boosting method?

Tags: boosting

I was wondering if someone  can please  link me to an academic   source  that shows the disadvantages of the boosting method?

Comment: One disadvantage is that they are sensitive to outliers and capable of fitting to noise. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140215/why-boosting-method-is-sensitive-to-outliers/465886#465886

Comment: Wikipedia has a fair commentary on the subject here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boosting_(machine_learning) and also provides some 20 references and associated online links as well. As Wikipedia comments:"The main variation between many boosting algorithms is their method of weighting training data points and hypotheses", I suspect a 'problem' may arise around the choice of weights in particular cases.